# I received an error Importing CSV file to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I used the following code to try to import a csv file into rails.
(it was provided by Erik on Rails blog)

```
#lib/tasks/import.rake
desc "Imports a CSV file into an ActiveRecord table"
task :csv_model_import, :filename, :model, :needs => :environment do |task,args|
  lines = File.new(args[:filename]).readlines
  header = lines.shift.strip
  keys = header.split(',')
  lines.each do |line|
    values = line.strip.split(',')
    attributes = Hash[keys.zip values]
    Module.const_get(args[:model]).create(attributes)
  end
end
```

then I ran the rake task rake csv_model_import[excelfilename.csv, name]. I have tried many approaches but just cant seem to get the csv file into my db/active record.

Error I received was : 
"NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for :needs:Symbol"

I have no clue how to solve it. Please help me out guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need brackets around your rake task arguments.

Try changing this:

```
task :csv_model_import, :filename, :model, :needs => :environment do |task,args|
```

to this:

```
task :csv_model_import, [:filename, :model, :needs] => :environment do |task,args|
```

Comment: Made Change, had to also put [:environment] into the square brackets. Now it fails sltently. I run the rake command and it does not create the table. My Schema file remains empty after running it.

Comment: Time to put some `puts` statements in there to find out what's going on. If you are using pry, you could also do `binding.pry` statements to debug.